# Setting Height to 100% Not Working and Unknown CSS Change

Tags: html, css, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I'm working on http://pizzli.com/darrenwp/?p=107. When I try and set the post background height to 100% to extend the background to the entire length of the post, it doesn't work, however changing the number of pixels does. One other problem is the HTML> seemed to set a Margin-Top: 28px !important and I'm not sure where this is coming from.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why have you got multiple element structures within an h2 tag?
and I don't really understand what you mean by the second problem

Comment: I didn't originally develop the theme, so I'm fixing issues. Take a look at the page and the Navigation bar seems to be moved down. I checked with FireFix Inspect Element and the HTML Class has margin-top: 28px !important added to it?

Comment: I can change #postbg's height to an actual number, however 100% does nothing

Comment: I couldn't recreate your problem, when setting the height to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `float` in an element so you  have to `clear` his parent. write now inside `#postbg` the `child` have `float` on it so we have to clear it. Write like this:

```
#postbg {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I just thought of that also! Any idea about the other issue?

Comment: I figured it out, it was creating space for the WPAdmin Bar

Answer (score 0):

In style.css your #postarea is declared twice. The second declaration looks like this:

```
#postarea{
float:left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

That could be overriding the height definition in the first

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-Top: 28px !important
```

Is for the workpress bar on the top of the page. Its not the problem.